About an elliptic fibration over an elliptic curve (inducing an etale morphism between elliptic curves)
(cf. "introduction to the Mori program" by K. Matsuki; page 65) Suppose $\alpha:S\to C$ is a smooth morphism from a smooth projective surface to a smooth elliptic curve whose (all) fibers are smooth elliptic curves. Take a very ample divisor $H$ such that $H\vert_F$ is an effective divisor of degree $m=H\cdot F$. Then since $F\cong Pic^0(F)$ (this follows from the fact that $F$ is an elliptic curve), there exist exactly $m^2$ distinct points $p^F_1,\cdots,p^F_{m^2}$ such that $p^F_i$ is linearly equivalent to $H\vert_F$.

Then it is said $G'=\{ p^F_i: i=1,\cdots,m^2; F\text{ all the fibers} \}\to C$ is an etale morphism from $G'$ to the elliptic curve $C$. (or whether $G'$ is of pure dimension 1 or not)

Here, I cannot figure out why the map $G'\to C$ should be etale. I even cannot figure out whether the given $G'$ is a (Zariski) closed subset of $S$ or not.
Once we assume $G'$ is closed disjoint union of irreducible curve, then the claim follows easily by inducing a contradiction under the assumption the map $G'\to C$ has ramification. But without knowing how $G'$ really looks like, I have no idea.
